# browser needs to be refreshed many times to display new picture

Tags: image

I give the user the opportunity of decorating his homepage with a large picture of his choice.
After submitting:

- **1** The new uploaded picture gets resized and renamed ( and replaces the former one in the `uploads/home` directory. It is renamed as homepic.jpg  which is ever the same name => the one that is mentionned in the `css` )
- **2** The pic appears in a `<div>` whose background image is :  `background-image: url("uploads/home/homepic.jpg");`

The advantage of this method is that if the format of the new uploaded picture does  not match perfectly the  `<div>` format  ( too square or too rectangle )
this does not lead to a display error: a thin strip of  the  picture is lost at the bottom or a the side , which is not disturbing at all.

The only problem is that  **the homepage needs to be refreshed 2/3/4/5 or 6 times** ,  in order to see the new uploaded pic appear.(Worst with chrome: up to 20 times)
Oddly when you upload a new pic for the 2nd time it is displayed immediatly .

Anyway , I would like it to work from the very first time and not have to rely on user's manual refresh.

I am using `Wamp` at the time being. I also tried to add `header("Cache-Control: no-cache");` .

What could I do to solve this or would there be another way to perform what I want ?

Comment: Since your visitor directly receives the images through Apache, you have to either 1. Implement a script to put the image through or 2. Edit your webserver (Apache) settings in order to not cache the directory or validate the cache more often.

Comment: "not cache" - terrible idea, "validate cache more often" won't get "refresh on first reload" 100% accurate

Comment: Depends on the amount of visitors. Since SunnyOne is using Wamp his amount of visitors might be reasonably small.

Comment: I am trying that with Wamp during developpement, I intend to put online when I'll have hired the server of course, was just mentionning Wamp to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ochi, user228395 
thanks to your discussion I found a solution which works very well in my case.

***homepage :***

- `<div id="home" style="background-image: url(uploads/home/homepic.jpg);"></div>`

***End of page : resizing + inserting in DB***

- `header('location:index.php?page=uploaded');` 
   This page says "your picture has been successfully uploaded ".
  When the user clicks the message or home button he is redirected to the home page and the latest uploaded picture is displayed immediatly.

Answer (score 1):

picture is being cached in browser - if you request for same resource (same URL) it won't be downloaded again

so after you change that image try to add something to it's address like get parameters

```
background-image: url("uploads/home/homepic.jpg?v=3");
```

now the tricky part is - that declaration exists in your CSS file so you really have only one option - move that CSS declaration as inline on that div

edit:
another point - if you would like to allow user to change that "homepic" it shouldn't be addressed like that - there should be catalog for each of users where they could store such things - that way you will end up with "uploads/userxxx/home/homepic.jpg?v=1"

Comment: Although your answer might solve the problem, this is not how the web is supposed to be build. The solution is cumbersome.

Comment: well if you insist on such "good" solution then he would need add another css stylesheet (user-stylesheet.css) with overwritten definition for that div - it's much more "cumbersome" than just put it inline (even if I agree with You that inline "is not how the web is supposed to be build") - it would simply be "over-engineered"

Comment: The concern is that file information belongs in meta-data provided by the webserver. Generating CSS to make the browser trick into downloading the new image is a workaround.

Comment: and still it's so called **standard** in such situations

Comment: Please provide facts. As far as I am concerned in professional webdevelopment this is not the way to go.

Comment: yes it is - from one side you try to provide users with option to extend site behavior - from performance point of view it's best to move it to inline instead of pushing another resource to be downloaded (user stylesheet) - not to mention time that must be taken to program solution you are talking about

Comment: You just should never pull an image with a version id, thats it. Never said a thing about inline or not.

Comment: and why I shouldn't use version numbers on images? "proffessional webdevelopment" is GTD - and in such changing version numbers of resources during pushing to production **IS STANDARD WAY** of doing things when you want to be sure that client will be using newest version

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31040/discussion-between-ochi-and-user228395)

Comment: @Ochi You are right, but in my project the user I am talking about is at the same time the owner of the website, so there will only be one user who 's going to upload pics. Thanks